# Overlay over chrome tab

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome-extension

Is it possible to add overlay over chrome tab which would look something like this:

[image: tabs with overlay]

Comment: No, not possible.

Answer (score 1):

I'm afraid not, at least not without directly editing the source code of the browser (which is impractical and dangerous, to say the least.) Chrome only has built in support for customizing the [tab group color](https://support.google.com/a/users/answer/10392467?hl=en#:%7E:text=Select%20a%20color%20for%20the%20tab.), [background of a new tab](https://support.google.com/a/users/answer/10391679?hl=en#:%7E:text=Add%20a%20custom%20background%20image%20to%20a%20tab), and [browser color](https://support.google.com/a/users/answer/10391679?hl=en#:%7E:text=Change%20your%20browser%20color). You also have the freedom to customize your [extension menus as a developer](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/mv3/getstarted/#user_interface), but that's about it.